# Gpt2 train on google colab (ram is not enough)

Tags: python

It is the first time that I approach this type of machine learning (finetune) and I have doubts:

1) I have a dataset of about 500M but on google colab I can't load it entirely in ram and mallock error, now the question is: can I split the dataset into smaller parts? will I have less gain on the model? (Calculating that the dataset is composed of songs delimited by prefix and truncate tags)

2) If the answer to question 1 is yes: what do you recommend?